# where is Gossip parameters set in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra-2.0

when I restart C*, I see the following message:
GossipTasks:1 ....FailureDetector.java:249 - Not marking nodes down due to local pause of 61578581871 > 5000000000

where is 5000000000 setup? can it be changed?

env: C* 2.19 on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is defined [in FailureDetector.java](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/b62fde1bb711ac48f7286371fbc6d661b4c69af6/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/gms/FailureDetector.java#L49-L64).

It can be overridden by specifying the system property `cassandra.max_local_pause_in_ms`

```
-Dcassandra.max_local_pause_in_ms=3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this gives another warn, so if purpose was to get rit of initial warn then it doesn't matter:)

> WARN  [Background_Reporter:1] 2016-08-19 11:46:55,778
>   FailureDetector.java:59 - Overriding max local pause time to 10000ms